# How did I create an RDP connection that resizes?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I have somehow created an RDP connection that does what I want, ie. I can stretch it so the text is large enough to read on my retina display.

Unfortunately, I want to do the same thing for other connections, but cannot figure out how to do it.

The connection that resizes larger has a "window" icon. The connection that will only resize smaller has a "computer" icon. Both have smart resize on. Both have zoom dimmed.

[image: RDP taskbar popup]

[image: window menu]

I have searched registry entries, `Default.rdp`, the RDP console, but cannot figure out how to do it. I have tried selecting "Use all my monitors" and can then minimise the window and stretch it, but the text is still tiny, and this does not result in the desired connection.

[image]

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Windows 10

Installed RDP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works.

I downloaded RDP from the Microsoft store and can select appropriate display settings here (and also resize larger).

[image]

Comment: Are you saying this solves your problem(s)? If so, could you make that more clear in sentence or two you can edit into this answer?